# How to rename url's using rewrite_mod?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am not a professional but with help from SO I was able to rename the profile page URL's for users on my project using `Rewrite_mod` using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

This works good. But I can't figure out how to give a specific name to a particular page. For example I have a page `profile_settings.php` when users go to that page I want it to be `example.com/settings` in the address bar. Tried few ways from SO like removing `.php` thought it will remove `php` extension for all files but It did not work at all. Now my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Was hoping `example.com/profile_settings.php` to be `example.com/profile_settings` but it did not work it's still full address with file extension. Moreover It will be good if I can deal with single file separately as besides removing extension I also want it to give desired name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrites for specific cases like `/settings -> /profile_settings.php` need to be handled separately and **before** other generic rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile_settings\.php[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /settings [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^settings/?$ profile_settings.php [L,NC]

# add .php extension if corresponding .php file exists    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# handle profile page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: typing `example.com/settings` manually in address bar does take me to settings page with same address (example.com/settings) in bar, but when I navigate to settings page from main menu the address in the bar is still example.com/profile_settings.php , how can I change it?